# Eliminating " " from a JSON file so that they don't interrupt the string

Tags: python, json, string, character

I have a huge JSON file that looks like this (I copy-pasted a lot but the error is at the beginning in this example):

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "title":"Title1",
      "paragraphs":[
        {
          "context":"In this text, one of the "words" is between quotation marks",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":515,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661182"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":505,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f4190066345"
             }
            ]
           },
           {
          "context":"Context2",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":515,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661182"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":505,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f4190066345"
             }
            ]
           }
          ]
         },
         {
         "title":"Title2",
      "paragraphs":[
        {
          "context":"Context10",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":585,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900661682"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":545,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41900663"
             }
            ]
           },
           {
          "context":"Context7",
          "qas":[
            {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":525,
                "text":"String text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why something something?",
             "id":"5733be284776f41982"
             },
             {
             "answers":[
               {
                "answer_start":595,
                "text":"String something text"
               }
              ],
             "question": "Why?",
             "id":"5733be284776f419005"
             }
            ]
           }
          ]
         }
         ],
          "version":"1.1"
         }
```

When I work with this file in Python (I want to change its structure), the quotation marks within the string break the string, so it gives me an error. I tried to `replace` it in Python, but this is problematic since I don't want the `""` delimitating the string to disappear. I can't delete them manually either because the file is huge.

This is the code for changing the structure, but I suppose this is a problem for every JSON file:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

result = []

for article in data["data"]:
    for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        for qa in paragraph["qas"]:
            answers = {"text": [answer["text"] for answer in qa["answers"]]}
            result.append({
                "id": qa["id"], 
                "context": paragraph["context"], 
                "question": qa["question"], 
                "answers": answers
            })

with open('output.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(result, fh)
```

Comment: This should be fixed at the source. How is the"JSON" generated?

Comment: @Klaus D. The JSON was originally in English and I translated it to German using DeepL. A lot of words being foreign, the translator just puts them between quotation marks. There is unfortunately no way to fix it from the source unless I manually translate it or I manually find the problems, which is impossible.

Comment: You should not translate the whole JSON, you should translate the strings in the JSON.

Comment: Did you translate the whole JSON? You could temporarily replace double quotes with something not used in the strings (e.g. `#`), translate it, then escape double quotes, and finally replace `#`s back to `"`. Translating a serialisation format sounds dangerous, though. There might be other subtle errors and the AI translator may also do a better job if you feed the strings individually.

Comment: @Selcuk I translated the whole JSON since just translating the strings would still place the English idiom/name/etc. into quotation marks. So the original text is "He celebrated the golden Jubilee" and the translation is "Er feierte das "goldene Jubiläum"."

Comment: Yes, but you could've escaped them before putting them back into JSON. Anyway, I posted a workaround in a comment above.

Comment: @Selcuk Sorry, I gave an example on top of my head, the texts that I have in the JSON are quite long and they appear from time to time.